# Recover data lost in a field while doing data type conversion

Tags: custom-field, data

Yesterday i did a data type conversion for a field from Multi-select picklist to Single select picklist.
While doing this it gave me warning about losing data but i wasn't aware of the data loss in data type conversion. I did data type conversion and saw that data from multi select picklist was gone.

Is there any way i can get back that 1 field data?

Comment: It isn't clear from your question exactly what data you lost (and are trying to recover). Did you 1) lose picklist values (all values, or all but one?) stored in the records of your object or 2) lose the picklist values from the field definition itself? Without a backup, I believe it is impossible to recover from situation #1. Recovering from situation #2 may be possible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could always go through the [Data Restoration Service](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000003594&type=1), but it takes about three weeks and $10,000 (USD). Unfortunately, if you didn't back up the data yourself, there's no way to get it back without using the service I just linked. The data loss warning is in place for a reason. In the future, make sure you're taking regular backups of your data.